# Remove a substring from cells in range by replacing or left string functions

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to keep the first 9 characters in the cells with more than 6 characters in column **A:A** of `Sheet1`:

```
Sub left_string_column()

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
If wb.Sheets.Len(cell.Value) > 5 Then cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 9)
Next cell

End Sub
```

I get an error in `For Each cell In wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")`

Why is that?

Or alternatively, how can I modify this code to remove **.txt** from the cell values in column **A:A** of `Sheet1`? 
For this I am using this one, but again, there is an error when running it:

```
Sub Delete_txt_file_names()
Dim Cel As Range, Range As Range
Dim Word As String
    Set Range = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
    Word = ".txt"

    For Each Cel In Range
        If Cel Like "*" & Word & "*" Then
            Cel = Replace(Cel, Word, "")
           End If
    Next Cel
End Sub
```

why is that?

Comment: You must **Set** the variable *wb* to some workbook.

Comment: `Dim Range As Range` ◄ **BAD** Don;t use reserved words as the name(s) of your variables. `Dim Word As String` is troublesome but `Range As Range` is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta include the `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook`
like this: 
**for the first code:**

```
Sub left_string_column()

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
If Len(cell.Value) > 6 Then cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 9)
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and the second code should be like this:

```
Sub Delete_txt_file_names()
Dim Cel As Range, Rng As Range
Dim Word As String
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Rng = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
    Word = ".txt"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Cel In Rng
        If Cel Like "*" & Word & "*" Then
            Cel = Replace(Cel, Word, "")
        End If
    Next Cel
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I hope this works now for you.